# VS2019: Can't add OpenAPI service reference to .NET Standard class library?

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2019, openapi, .net-standard-2.0, service-reference

When I try to add an OpenAPI service reference (from a valid .json file) to my .Net Standard 2.0 class library, Visual Studio 2019 throws the following error message at me (message box): "*Project needs to be restored before the service reference can be added*". What does that mean? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Then I tried it with a .Net Core Library instead and it worked without a hitch. I think .Net Standard is the wrong library type.